# Converting JQuery SideBar Menu to AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am having some difficulty with my angularJs conversion.

Simply put, when a user clicks to expand a respective parent menu item, all the parent menu items expand to show the sub items. Obviously this is not what I am trying to achieve.

***The end result I am looking for:***

**When a user clicks on a parent item, any current expanded node collapses and that respective parent node current clicked expands.**

Really would be EXTREMELY grateful if someone could replicate my plunker to achieve the desired goals stated.

Thanks so much !!!!

- **[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8tOkrcAgmVzc0jRjBBdQ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6hKIcUAwpIePyjk1K7Ic?p=preview

Just keep track of the item that is expanded and store that on your scope. Then in your view you can just check if the current item in the ng-repeat is equal to the expanded item stored on the scope.

Comment: Thanks. Always seems so obvious after someone points out the error.